# Rake test failed using metriks

Tags: ruby, rake

I downloaded https://github.com/eric/metriks and did

```
bundle install
gem install minitest
```

I still get the error below:

```
$ rake test
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -I"lib:lib:test" -I"/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib" "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/**/*_test.rb" 
Warning: you should require 'minitest/autorun' instead.
Warning: or add 'gem "minitest"' before 'require "minitest/autorun"'
From:
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/purpletech/metriks/test/test_helper.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/purpletech/metriks/test/counter_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `each'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `block in <main>'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `select'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `<main>'
MiniTest::Unit::TestCase is now Minitest::Test. From /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit/testcase.rb:8:in `<module:Unit>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:670:in `<class:Runner>': undefined method `_run_suite' for class `Test::Unit::Runner' (NameError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:255:in `<module:Unit>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:9:in `<module:Test>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/purpletech/metriks/test/test_helper.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/purpletech/metriks/test/counter_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `block in <main>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `select'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `<main>'
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [ruby -I"lib:lib:test" -I"/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib" "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/**/*_test.rb" ]

Tasks: TOP => test
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to learn to [format your question](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and the sections in the question to make it more readable. As is, you'll discourage help as potential answerers will glance at it and not want to slog through the text trying to figure out what is what.

Comment: What happened when you followed `Warning: you should require 'minitest/autorun' instead.
Warning: or add 'gem "minitest"' before 'require "minitest/autorun"'`?

Comment: i grepped for minitest and nothing came up

Answer (score 0):

According to your logs a test uses the old class name `MiniTest::Unit::TestCase` which is currenly `Minitest::Test`. Try to replace the old name by the new one.

Comment: That package doesnt have MiniTest::Unit::TestCase it has Test::Unit::TestCase and I replace it with Minitest::Test . I still get the error. Should I ask that github group ?